# Installing MySql 5.5.31 on Mac OSX 10.9?

Tags: mysql

I'm attempting to install a previous version of MySql (5.5.31) on my Mac OSX device running 10.9 Mavericks. I have been told this is possible, however, I cannot seem to locate a download for 5.5.31 Mac OSX.

I have a later version (5.6.19) installed, and I tried:

```
brew switch mysql 5.5.31
```

but I keep getting the error message:

```
"Error: mysql not found in the Cellar."
```

And I know this is because there's no 5.5.31 MySql file for it to switch to.

Anyone do this on their Mac?

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is an old question, but I stumbled upon it through Google, so here's to anyone to stumbles upon it later.

I was trying to install MySQL 5.5 on OS X 10.10 through Homebrew.

First, you have to add homebrew/versions to your taps with:

```
$ homebrew tap homebrew/versions
```

Second, install MySQL 5.5 with:

```
$ homebrew install mysql55
```

if that doesn't work, try:

```
$ homebrew install homebrew/versions/mysql55
```

After that has successfully installed, you will get the message:

> ...A "/etc/my.cnf" from another install may interfere with a
>   Homebrew-built server starting up correctly.
>
> To connect:
>       mysql -uroot
>
> To load mysql55:
>       launchctl load ~/Library/LaunchAgents/homebrew.mxcl.mysql55.plist Or, if you don't want/need launchctl, you can just run:
>       mysql.server start ❯ cd /usr/local/Cellar/mys

Try mysql.server start, if that doesn't work you need to update your $PATH. In my case I added /usr/local/Cellar/mysql55/5.5.40/bin to my $PATH in my .zshrc. You can find the location of your installation by using:

```
$ homebrew info mysql55
```

After that it should work after you've added that directory to your .zshrc/.bashrc/.bash_profile etc.